# Change a solid color of a png with transparent background, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just have a little png, that is used as a "grid" by using background repeat, the format of the image for the grid would be something like this |_  then just repeat itself to cover the whole body.

Now the thing is, is there a possibility to change its color by using CSS3 ? not the background of the image but the lines only.

Saw that there's a "filter" attribute in CSS3, but I don't know which one to use or if it's the best way to do it.

Basically the color of the grid would be based on a color picker in RGB or Hex format.
If there's any way to add any color i want to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hue rotate filter in your CSS.  It doesn't work in all browsers, but in some:

```
filter: hue-rotate(180deg)
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Imagine that i got a color picker where i could choose any color i want, in hex or rgb format :( is it possible to add any color i want?

Comment: @msqar Why wouldn't you just re-make your image in SVG at that point?

Comment: re-make the image in SVG? :O

Comment: Yeah, it's just a grid, right?  Or use `<canvas>` if you need to change it often.  If you must use an image with varying color, I suppose you could even leave it as PNG but use an indexed palette, and change the palette color by modifying the contents of the file directly.

Comment: I need to read about the SVG thing, because that's what i want to do :) basically i got a piece of grid in a light blue with transparent background and then i want to change the grid color on the fly, i will do some research, thanks!

Comment: oh damn :( i have to add the 64base code every time i change the color of the grid?

Comment: No...  SVG can be manipulated with JavaScript.  And, why are you base-64-encoding your image?

Comment: Yea you're right, it's not needed just by using <svg> tags. Is SVG HTML5 compliant?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could add opacity to your background image, and change the background color in the same id/class to the desired color. It won't change the color of the lines but give the illusion of a particular color on those lines.